# Visual Studio android emulator httprequest fails

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator

So I've been working on a xamarin PCL project targeting android and windows store app and I've had this issue for about two weeks now. One of the very first things this app does is to make an http request to a yahoo service when the user tries to search for something. 
Now, on the windows store app project, this works just fine. However, whenever I'm debugging the android project, this fails miserably. It times out and I get a TaskAbortedException. 
I've navigated with the browser within the android emulator to the restful service url and I do get a response in the browser but nothing when I make the http request. I have tried everything I could think of but no cigar. I have researched this for weeks now and I have yet to find an answer. It should be noted that I'm making the request within the PCL project with HttpClient.
Here's the code where this happens:

```
    var queryUrl = string.Format(QUERY_URL_TEMPLATE, TickerSearch);
    try
    {
        var requestTask = httpClient.GetStringAsync(queryUrl);
        requestTask.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            var responseDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TickerSearchResultDto>(t.Result);

            TickerSearchResults = responseDto.ResultSet.Result;
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: how about creating an async method and putting await where you say `GetStringAsync` and also check the `IsSuccessStatusCode` in the responce.

Comment: Have you added the "INTERNET" permission in your project properties of the Android app?